# Can't get a ASP.Net Core Docker Image to run in Azure container web app

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have been trying for several days to get an Azure Linux Container Web App to run. I have a web site frontend built in Angular and an asp.net core 3.1 backend that this all runs in, and I have a Dockerfile that builds it all.

The angular site is hosted from within asp.net core wwwroot folder.

I can run the app standalone with no problems. I can also run it in Docker desktop with no issues.

```
docker build MyApp -t myapp
docker run -d -p 80:80 myapp:latest -e environment='Production' -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production'
```

I am then building this dockerfile in Devops with a .yml pipeline and pushing to an Azure ACR with:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build And Push
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    repository: $(imageName)
    Dockerfile: $(dockerFile)
    tags: 'myapp'
```

This also works and I can see it being pushed to the Azure Container Registry.

I then restart the Azure Web App so that it restarts with the latest image and get the following in the console.

```
2020-04-21 06:39:30.400 INFO  - Pulling image: acrmyapp.azurecr.io/myapp-web:myapp
2020-04-21 06:39:31.736 INFO  - myapp Pulling from myapp-web
2020-04-21 06:39:31.738 INFO  -  Digest: sha256:f64056681fdc66939b362196a3293aea9baa311340293c17664c36d77088a49d
2020-04-21 06:39:31.740 INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for acrmyapp.azurecr.io/myapp-web:bt
2020-04-21 06:39:31.745 INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 1 Seconds
2020-04-21 06:39:31.775 INFO  - Starting container for site
2020-04-21 06:39:31.776 INFO  - docker run -d -p 4880:80 --name web-prod-bt_0_e32966d1 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=web-prod-bt -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=web-prod-bt.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=5c117bc5116941ff3fb1eb90511ac2f83e1adddea111b14577d6ea1fb7356b3d -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 acrmyapp.azurecr.io/myapp-web:bt -e WEBSITES_PORT=80 -e environment='Production' -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production'
2020-04-21 06:39:32.904 INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container web-prod-bt_0_e32966d1 for site web-prod-bt

2020-04-21 06:39:34.954 ERROR - Container web-prod-bt_0_e32966d1 for site web-prod-bt has exited, failing site start
2020-04-21 06:39:34.957 ERROR - Container web-prod-bt_0_e32966d1 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2020-04-21 06:39:34.968 INFO  - Stoping site web-prod-bt because it failed during startup.
```

If I run the same command locally in Docker Desktop (On windows 10), just replacing the source of the image, it works.

```
docker run -d -p 4880:80 --name web-prod-bt_0_e32966d1 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=web-prod-bt -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=web-prod-bt.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=5c117bc5116941ff3fb1eb90511ac2f83e1adddea111b14577d6ea1fb7356b3d -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 acrmyapp.azurecr.io/myapp-web:bt -e WEBSITES_PORT=80 -e environment='Production' -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production'
```

My best guess right now is that Azure tries to verify that the container is running in some manner that I dont understand and fails at doing so and stops the service.

I have found other threads concerning this such as:

- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/46401
- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34451

But the only thing I could really gather out of those is that I need to set `-e PORT=80`, which I already am.

Would really appreciate some help on what I should try.

Edit, if it helps here is the Dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Backend", "backend"]
RUN dotnet restore "backend/src/myapp.Web/myapp.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "backend/src/myapp.Web"
RUN dotnet build "myapp.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# Angular
FROM node:12.2.0 as angular
WORKDIR /src
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY ["Frontend/myapp-frontend-v2", "frontend"]
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
WORKDIR /src/frontend 
RUN npm install
RUN ng build --prod --output-path=/app/dist

# Publish
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myapp.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=angular /app/dist /app/wwwroot

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.Web.dll"]
```

**Update 1:** I read here: https://omgdebugging.com/2017/12/22/azure-web-app-for-container-failing-site-start/ that it could be caused by incorrect line endings in the Dockerfile, where Azure crashes if the line endings are anything other than /lf. I used notepad++ to check this, and made sure to only have unix/linux type of line endings. But this made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The error was in these paramaters:

```
-e environment='Production' -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production'
```

They have to be specified without ', this works:

```
-e environment=Production -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

I originally also specified `-e WEBSITES_PORT=80` in the Container Startup script, it was not needed.

I have specified these extra startup values in Web App > Container Settings > Startup File (form field), same value can be edited from Web App > Configuration > Startup Command (its the same field with a different name).